# Windows XP/7 filesystem name substitution

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, wmi

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) a developer could access the filesystem name by retrieving `Win32_LogicalDisk` class. This class has a field `FileSystem` with following properties:

```
Data type: string
Access type: Read-only
File system on the logical disk.
Example: "NTFS"
```

Are there any ways to substitute the string `NTFS` by any other custom string like `MegaFS` of the already mounted volume causes the system will report the mounted volume has `MegaFS` type?

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem type is determined by reading drive information stored on the disk.  The driver used to read that information presents the name to Windows.  In other words, you would need to write your own NTFS driver for Windows that reported it as something else.

Comment: Understood, I have found the according sources in `fastfat` DDK example. Is it possible to write some filter driver that will linked in runtime somehow with an already loaded driver such as `NTFS` and override the native `NTFS` routine responding the `FileFsAttributeInformation`-queries by mine custom implementation reporting there is an `MegaFS` volume?